# Problem downloading files from link android java

Tags: java, android, download

I have a link where if we go, the .mp4 file will be downloaded automatically, but if the try to do using the download manager then the files is saved as .html format which I want in .mp4.

```
String ID = "https://presaver.com/download/9Tw-f3i-08k/22";
 DownloadManager downloadmanager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("ID");
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
        request.setTitle("YoutubeVideo");
        request.setDescription("Downloading youtube video");
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);
        request.setDestinationUri(Uri.parse(path));
        downloadmanager.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: `(Uri.parse(path))` Well what is the value of path?

Answer (score 1):

I think you miswrote this line

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("ID");
```

It should be

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(ID); // string ID
```

Comment: or try to change `https` to `http` .